# How to plot summation over exp function in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any short way to plot the following summation of exp function?

```
plot f1*exp(-0.001*(x-L1)^2) +  f2*exp(-0.001*(x-L2)^2) + etc
```

where **f** and **L** values are sorted in coulmns **1** & **2** in the file **data.dat**, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

So line `i` of file contains `f_i L_i` ? You can do this using a call to a function:

```
sumval=0
add(x)=(sumval=sumval+x)
plot "file.dat" using 0:(add($1*exp(-0.001*(x-$2)**2)))
```

(here the abscissae will be in terms of line number, pseudo-column `$0`)
Here `x` is assumed to be fixed before, issuing e.g. a `x=...` command.

But I guess what you wanted is for any `x` values, plot the result of the summation?

Then you would need to do a large number of these sums, plotting only the last point for each `x`.

```
N_samples=100 # number of points to plot
Xmin=0
Xmax=1.
x(ix)=Xmin+(Xmax-Xmin+0.)*ix/N_samples
stats "data.dat" 
N=STATS_records
sumval=0
currec=0
finished(v)=(sumval=0,currec=0,v) #reinitialise the counters
add(y)=(currec=currec+1,sumval=sumval+y,(currec==N)?finished(sumval):1/0)
plot [Xmin:Xmax] for [ix=0:N_samples] "file.dat" using (x(ix)):(add($1*exp(-0.001*(x(ix)-$2)**2)))
```

You'll not be able to join points with a line unless you first redirect your plot to a table and then plot that table.